# How to create a post box with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a social media site from scratch, and I was wonder how to create a post box like this using html and css. So far I haven’t found ANYTHING. Please help if you can!
[image: Post Box]

Comment: if you want to do a social media site, you wont come far with HTML and CSS. it requires JS aswell and specifically PHP. YOu cant program a safe enviroment for multiple users with integrated CMS with HTML and CSS only. That "post box" is nothing else then a `<textarea>`. But like I said, with HTML and CSS you wont come far or potencially will face some lawsuits asoon as you lose control what users going to post.

Comment: @tacoshy I am using php as well, I just need a way to make the text area look like that

Comment: so where is your front-end code then? what have you tried so far? where are you stuck? what isnt working for you yet?  ---  Please note that SO is not a plattform where users will do all the coding for you. It requires some own research efford aswell as some coding on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is what you want?**
I have a code only like this in my source

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* * Post widget * */

input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.btn {
  padding: .5em 1em;

  background-color: transparent;
  color: #6b7270;

  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.widget-post {
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;

  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 1px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.1);

  background-color: #fff;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.widget-post__header {
  padding: .2em .5em;

  background-color: #eaeaea;
  color: #3f5563;
}
.widget-post__title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.widget-post__content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.widget-post__textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .5em;

  border: none;
  resize: none;
}
.widget-post__textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.widget-post__options {
  padding: .5em;
}
.widget-post___input {
  display: inline-block;

  width: 24%;
  padding: .2em .5em;

  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
}
.post-actions__label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.widget-post__actions {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
}
.post--actions {
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em;

  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #a2a6a7;
}
.post-actions__attachments {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}
.attachments--btn {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  color: #007582;

  border-radius: 1.5em;
}

.post-actions__widget {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 38%;
  text-align: right;
}
.post-actions__publish {
  width: 120px;

  background-color: #008391;
  color: #fff;

  border-radius: 1.5em;
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.is--hidden {
  display: none;
}

.sr-only {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;

  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
  clip-path: inset(50%);

  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;

}


/* *  Placeholder contrast * */
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-post" aria-labelledby="post-header-title">
  <div class="widget-post__header">
    <h2 class="widget-post__title" id="post-header-title">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Write Me
    </h2>
  </div>
  <form id="widget-form" class="widget-post__form" name="form" aria-label="post widget">
    <div class="widget-post__content">
      <label for="post-content" class="sr-only">Share</label>
      <textarea name="post" id="post-content" class="widget-post__textarea scroller" placeholder="What's wrong with r00tme?"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-post__options is--hidden" id="stock-options">
    </div>
    <div class="widget-post__actions post--actions">
      <div class="post-actions__attachments">
        <button type="button" class="btn post-actions__stock attachments--btn" aria-controls="stock-options" aria-haspopup="true">
          <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          stock
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn post-actions__upload attachments--btn">
          <label for="upload-image" class="post-actions__label">
             <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            upload image
          </label>
        </button>
        <input type="file" id="upload-image" accept="image/*" multiple>
      </div>
      <div class="post-actions__widget">
        <button class="btn post-actions__publish">publish</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```